# Actualizar un sección mediante una consulta

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Necesito actualizar un `div` en cada segundo, pero este `div` tiene una consulta no me ha funcionado correctamente, ya que esta haciendo un consulta a mysql. No sé si tengo agregar algo mas, ya que nunca carga nada de la BD

```
     <?php
     include "../config/config.php";
    $id_ticket=7;
     ?>
     <head>

     </head>
     <body>

    <div id="comen">
         <?php


                            $come=mysqli_query($con, "select* from comentario where id_ticket='".$id_ticket."' order  by  fecha_comen desc");
                            foreach($come as $c):?>

                                 <?php
                                 $userb=$c['id_usuario'];
                                 $users=mysqli_query($con, "select * from user where id='".$userb."'");
                                 foreach($users as $u); 
                                 ?>        
                                  <div class="<?php echo $usercss;?>">
                                   <div class="date">
                                        <?php echo $c['fecha_comen'];?>
                                   </div>
                                           <div class="user">
                                              <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                               <span class="name">
                                                <?php echo $u['name'];?>
                                                </span>
                                                <span class="type">
                                                 <?php echo $u['email'];?>
                                                 </span>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="message">
                                               <p> <?php echo $c['comentario'];?><br/>
                                         </div>
                              </div>
                                <?php
                        endforeach; 
                         ?>
     </div>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var refreshId =  setInterval( function(){
        $('#comen').load("comen.php");//actualiza el div
       }, 1000 );

});
</script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Te comento lo siguiente.

Cuando por ejemplo están invocando un archivo externo, como en este caso el **comen.php**, debe ser entre comillas ya que de lo contrario javascript lo asume como variables que no sabe interpretar; entonces tu código debería quedar así

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var refreshId =  setInterval( function(){
    $('#comen').load("comen.php");//actualizas el div
   }, 1000 );
});
```

Comment: Es correcto, ya corregí esa parte pero sigue si cargarme automáticamente la consulta que se muestra en es div,

Comment: agrega el codigo de la consulta para ver que esta faltando

Comment: la consulta o la variable que contiene a esa consulta debe estar precedida por un echo para que se pueda imprimir en pantalla

Comment: Ahí está mi código

Comment: El * no debería estar separado del select o eso no influye?

Comment: no afecta en la ejecución

Comment: prueba con un echo o un return al inicio de la variable $come la que esta al mero inicio de tu código

Comment: todo me lo hace correctamente bien, el detalle que para que se ejecute ese código tengo que cargar la pagina y lo que yo quiero es que se haga en automático solo el div mencionado

Comment: Mi fin es que con el código JS se actualice todo lo del div automáticamente

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta de utilizar el setInterval debería ser algo como lo siguiente:

```js
function refrescar(){
  console.log("funciona");
}
```

```html
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Título de la página</TITLE>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
        
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        Aquí iría el contenido de la página
    </BODY>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var myVar = setInterval(refrescar,1000);
});
</script>
</HTML>
```